# Planck's law - spectral radiance per wavelength, wikipedia article

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength

I am looking at the [wikipedia article of the Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law). Is the second formula correct?
$$
B_\lambda (\lambda, T) = \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{e^\frac{hc}{\lambda k_B T} -1}
$$

If $f = \frac{c}{\lambda}$, should it not look like this?
$$
B_\lambda (\lambda, T) = \frac{2hc}{\lambda^3}\frac{1}{e^\frac{hc}{\lambda k_B T} -1}
$$

Comment: Yes, it’s correct. See [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law#Correspondence_between_spectral_variable_forms) of the article.

Comment: I understand now, thank you!